# How to convert lowercase uppercase?(with if conditions on different digits.)

Tags: javascript

Hi This is my first time using this website, I did do some research about how to convert lowercase letter to uppercase letter but still filles. The requirement is to check if "even", covert the even digit letter to different type(lower to upper or upper to lower). below is my code:

```
function question4(str,pos)
    {   var newLetter;
    var kkk=str;

        if (pos='even')
        {
            for (var i=0;i<str.length;i=i+2)
            {
                if (str[i].toString()==str[i].toString().toUpperCase())
                {
                    newLetter=str[i].toString().toLowerCase();
                    kkk[i]=newLetter;
                }else
                {
                    newLetter=str[i].toUpperCase();
                    kkk[i]=newLetter;
                }
            }
        }else if (pos='odd')
                    for ( i=0;i<str.length;i=i+2)
                    {
                        if (str[i]===str[i].toLowerCase())
                        {
                            alert('3');
                        }else if (str[i]===str[i].toUpperCase())
                        {
                            alert('4');
                        }
                    }
                    return kkk;
    }
```

the requirement is: Write a function to change the case of all the characters in string based on their position which matches the value of the pos parameter function. function (str, pos [even|odd]). Example ( (‘abCd’, ‘odd’) return Abcd)

Update: now I have make "odd" condition working, but "even "still is not working, can any one take a look why?

```
function question4(strr,pos) {
var result  ;
var sum="";
var aaa;

for (var i = 0; i <= strr.length - 1; i = i + 1)
{
    if (pos == "odd"&&i%2==0)
    {   aaa=strr.charCodeAt(i);

        if (aaa >= 65 && aaa <= 90 )
        {
            result = String.fromCharCode(aaa + 32);
        } else
            result = String.fromCharCode(aaa - 32);
    }
    else if (pos == "even"&&i%2==1)
    {
        if (aaa >= 65 && aaa <= 90 )
        {
            result= String.fromCharCode(aaa + 32);
        } else
            result = String.fromCharCode(aaa - 32);
    }else result=strr[i];
    sum+=result;
}


return sum;
```

}

Comment: so does this code work then? you haven't stated what the error is.

Comment: are you sure (‘abCd’, ‘odd’) return Abcd ? I mean, index of `a` is 0 not 1

Comment: I used my function and it never change the string.....

Comment: doesn't matter, as long as this one works, i can adjust the position, but the problem is this function is not working at all which makes me confused if any logic issue exist

Comment: this is not c; string are immutable

Comment: I tried, javascript won't work, must be in c environment. can anyone give advice on Javasript?

Comment: As I just checked the requirement, tolower or toupper is not allowed to use...

Comment: @DavidShi i edited my answer with others ways to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve this, you can construct a string by concating char by char:

```
function question4(strInput, pos) {
  let str = ""; // The string to construct
  if (!pos || (pos !== "even" && pos !== "odd")) { // Validating pos
    throw "invalid pos";
  }
 for (var i=0;i<strInput.length;i++) // Looping on strInput
 {  
   let huPos = i + 1;
   if ((pos === "even" && huPos%2 == 1) ||
      (pos === "odd" && huPos%2 == 0)) { 
/* If we want switch odd and we are on even position or if we want switch even and we are on odd position, then we add the original char
*/
     str += strInput[i];
   }
   else {
     // In others case, we switch lower to upper and upper to lower
     let char = strInput[i];
     str += char == char.toUpperCase() ? char.toLowerCase() : char.toUpperCase();
   }
 }
 return str;
}
console.log(question4('abCdef', "odd")); // Return "AbcdEf"
```

[Associated bin](https://jsbin.com/tiwiles/5/edit?js,console)

EDIT:

After seeing edit, i can see you want to do it without using toLower/UpperCase. As stated in comment i think it is a bad idea in js, but to experiment you can achieve this:

```
const reverser = {
  "a": "a".charCodeAt(0),
  "z": "z".charCodeAt(0),
  "A": "A".charCodeAt(0),
  "Z": "Z".charCodeAt(0),
};
const conversionValueToLower = reverser.a - reverser.A;
const conversionValueToUpper = reverser.A - reverser.a;
function reverseChar(char) {
  var code = char.charCodeAt(0);
    // If you want to go from upper to lower
    if (code >= reverser.A && code <= reverser.Z) {
       // Simply add the difference between lower and upper
      return String.fromCharCode(code + conversionValueToLower);
    } // Same logic here
    else if (code >= reverser.a && code <= reverser.z) {
      return String.fromCharCode(code + conversionValueToUpper);
    }
  /**
  Or use if you want full digit
  if (code <= 90 && code >= 65) {
    return String.fromCharCode(code + 32);
  }
  else if (code >= 97 && code <= 122) {
    return String.fromCharCode(code - 32);
  }
  **/
  return char; // Other case return original char
}

function question4(strInput, pos) {
  let str = "";
  if (!pos || (pos !== "even" && pos !== "odd")) {
    throw "invalid pos";
  }
 for (var i=0;i<strInput.length;i++)
 {  
   let huPos = i + 1;
   if ((pos === "even" && huPos%2 == 1) ||
      (pos === "odd" && huPos%2 == 0)) {
     str += strInput[i];
   }
   else {
     str += reverseChar(strInput[i]);
   }
 }
 return str;
}
console.log(question4('abCdef', "odd")); // return "AbcdEf"
```

[Associated bin](https://jsbin.com/tiwiles/10/edit?js,console)

Another way could be to code utils functions imitating toLower/UpperCase

I corrected your code in your answer aswell, without changing original logic

```
function question4(strr,pos) {
  var result  ;
  var sum="";
  var aaa;

  for (var i = 0; i <= strr.length - 1; i = i + 1)
  {
    if (pos == "odd"&&i%2==0)
    {   aaa=strr.charCodeAt(i);

     if (aaa >= 65 && aaa <= 90 )
     {
       result = String.fromCharCode(aaa + 32);
     } else if(aaa >=97&&aaa <=122)
     { result = String.fromCharCode(aaa - 32);}
     else {result=strr[i];}
    }
    else if (pos == "even"&&i%2==1)
    {   aaa=strr.charCodeAt(i);
     if (aaa >= 65 && aaa <= 90 )
     {
       result= String.fromCharCode(aaa + 32);
     } else if(aaa >=97&&aaa <=122)
     { result = String.fromCharCode(aaa - 32);}
     else {result=strr[i];}
    }else {result=strr[i];}
    sum+=result;
  }


  return sum;
}

console.log(question4("abCd", "odd")) // return Abcd;
```

Comment: thanks, what you did is exactly what I did. I took about 2 days to figure out this solution, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution for this question

```js
// Function used to invert the letter case
const changeCase = c => {
  if (c === c.toUpperCase()) return c.toLowerCase()
  return c.toUpperCase()
}

const swapCaseConditional = (str, pos) => {
  // Use split method to convert string into array and map the array
  return str.split('').map((c, index) => {
    if (pos === 'even') {
      // if pos and index are even, change the letter case
      if (index % 2) return changeCase(c)
      return c
    }
    else {
      // if pos and index are odd, change the letter case
      if (!(index%2)) return changeCase(c)
      return c
    }
    // Convert to string
  }).join('')
}

console.log(swapCaseConditional('abCd', 'odd'))
```

Comment: can you comment code. And the result is wrong, it return an array instead of a string

Answer (score 0):

I worked two nights and finally got it working. although not fully cover all the situations, but almost there.

```
function question4(strr,pos) {
var result  ;
var sum="";
var aaa;

for (var i = 0; i <= strr.length - 1; i = i + 1)
{
    if (pos == "odd"&&i%2==0)
    {   aaa=strr.charCodeAt(i);

        if (aaa >= 65 && aaa <= 90 )
        {
            result = String.fromCharCode(aaa + 32);
        } else
            result = String.fromCharCode(aaa - 32);
    }
    else if (pos == "even"&&i%2==1)
    {   aaa=strr.charCodeAt(i);
        if (aaa >= 65 && aaa <= 90 )
        {
            result= String.fromCharCode(aaa + 32);
        } else if(aaa >=97&&aaa <=122)
        { result = String.fromCharCode(aaa - 32);}
        else {result=strr[i];}
    }else {result=strr[i];}
    sum+=result;
}


return sum;
```

}

Comment: You are using C tactic. I think using UTF code for something so trivial is too much. More if/else you use, harder your code is to read/debug.
You must name variables correctly.
Same code is wrote twice.
And there is an error in your first `if` (that happen when you repeat your code).
Please check my answer and validate if you like.
Please indent and comment your code.

Comment: i edited my answer to meet your needs, you can check